# How to take a thread dump of a maven build

Tags: maven, thread-dump

I would like to take a thread dump of a maven run on CI server.
The thread dump should be taken for example every 10 minutes to debug hanged maven runs.
Is there an existing extention / configuration I could use?

If not, I will write one. For this task, would you recommend creating a plugin?
Will most internal maven plugins run on the same JVM?

I am working with maven 3.9.4.

Comment: I actually never had problems with hanged Maven builds. What kind of problems are you trying to debug?

Comment: Sometimes maven will just hang for 10 min during a build, no output at all to the console.

Comment: What I would suggest: First of all, I would run the build with `-X` flag to see debug output and see in exactly which Maven plugin the "hanging" happens. With this, you could probably ask a question here on StackOverflow. Secondly, you can try to debug the build in the IDE. I successfully debugged Maven builds in Eclipse in the past by starting them in debug mode and then looking at the line in the code where the build was waiting indefinitely.

Comment: If the build is only slow on the CI server it is most likely a network timeout issue.